# Limit laws in probability

Tags: limits, statistics, probability-distributions

I was working on a problem in mathematical statistics where I got to the following step,
$$f_X(x) = \lim_{\delta x \rightarrow 0}n\frac{P(nx <X'<x +\delta nx)}{\delta nx}$$
Where $X'$ is a random variable that is a function fo $X$. The above is basically just the definition of the pdf: $f_{X'}(nx)$
My question is can I claim that because $$\delta x \rightarrow 0$$ and $n$ is a constant (it is the sample size), we know that 
$$\delta nx \rightarrow 0$$ so we can re-write this as 
$$f_X(x) = \lim_{\delta nx \rightarrow 0}n\frac{P(nx <X'<x +\delta nx)}{\delta nx}$$
Furthermore, can I then pull the $n$ out even though **it is part of the limit** to get:
$$f_X(x) = n\lim_{\delta nx \rightarrow 0}\frac{P(nx <X'<x +\delta nx)}{\delta nx}$$
The reason I want to do this is so I can recognize the second part$$\lim_{\delta nx \rightarrow 0}\frac{P(nx <X'<x +\delta nx)}{\delta nx}$$ as just the definition of the pdf of $X'$ evaluated at the point $nx$ therefore claiming that 
$$f_X(x) = nf_{X'}(nx)$$

Are those steps valid?